# What can I change to make this code work properly?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm in the final stages of testing before I release the alpha version of a program I am writing. This may be a silly question but I just can't seem to figure it out. I understand what drjava is telling me, that I'm missing a variable, but I also don't understand because I never made a variable under the name "()". I'm not even sure you can set any type of variable to a open-close parenthesis. Anyways I was testing and while it works, it doesn't the way I want it to. I entered into the scanner "Mr. B." without the quotes of course. The program did not print the B. I'm thinking it might be the space in between Mr. and B, because other inputs with a space did the same. I can not release a version of my program knowing there is a GIANT glitch in the code. I'm wondering why, and I tried to fix it by changing ownersname.next(); to ownersname.nextLine and ownersname.next and ownersname.nextScanner and ownername.nextScanner. This is where the error comes in, when it says it can't find the variable until I change it back to it's original code, which is below.

```
Scanner ownersname = new Scanner(System.in);
   String sownersname = ownersname.next();
   System.out.println(sownersname + "? That is a nice name.");
```

Comment: What? drjava is telling you something--what is it? Who says you're missing a variable? What does an empty parenthesis have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm in the final stages of testing before I release the alpha version of a program I am writing.

You're creating a professional application? Please do tell us more about this.

---

> I understand what drjava is telling me, that I'm missing a variable, but I also don't understand because I never made a variable under the name "()". I'm not even sure you can set any type of variable to a open-close parenthesis.

When posting questions here, if you have an error message from the compiler, please post the entire error message with your question. Don't paraphrase it. And indicate by obvious comment in your code, i.e., `// ****** error here *****` where the error is occurring.

---

> Anyways I was testing and while it works, it doesn't the way I want it to. I entered into the scanner "Mr. B." without the quotes of course. The program did not print the B. I'm thinking it might be the space in between Mr. and B, because other inputs with a space did the same.

Don't use `Scanner#next()` which gets only the next token -- the next word before reaching whitespace (here, Mr.), and will not get the rest of the text on the line. Instead use `Scanner#nextLine()` which gets you the whole line.

For example:

```
Scanner ownersname = new Scanner(System.in);
// String sownersname = ownersname.next(); // *** not this ***
String sownersname = ownersname.nextLine(); // *** but rather this ***
System.out.println(sownersname + "? That is a nice name.");
```

---

> I can not release a version of my program knowing there is a GIANT glitch in the code.

Seriously, you're creating a professional application? I'm not yet at that stage, which is why I ask.

---

> I'm wondering why, and I tried to fix it by changing ownersname.next(); to ownersname.nextLine and ownersname.next and ownersname.nextScanner and ownername.nextScanner. This is where the error comes in, when it says it can't find the variable until I change it back to it's original code, which is below.

I'd be curious to see your `nextLine()` method attempt, because that is the solution. Perhaps you were trying to call the method without using the method parenthesis.

I also assume that you're familiar with the Java API and have looked up the Scanner entry for it. If you did, you would see right away that there is no `nextScanner()` method for this class. This is one reason I have to wonder about your making a professional application at your stage. Again, I don't feel that I'm at the stage yet to create one yet, so please don't take this as an insult, just a curiosity.